# Testing screen connected to redux in a react native app that uses react navigation - JEST

Tags: react-native, redux, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm learning how to test my components using Jest, but I'm having trouble testing my Login screen. The component is connected to Redux and is part of a navigator. I'm mocking my redux store, but I get the following error when running my tests:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/screens/Login.test.js
 Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined

> 1 | import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
  2 | import AppNavigator from "../navigators/AppNavigator";
  3 |
  4 | const NavigationInitialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction({

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/reduxHelpers.js:1:1287)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/reducers/index.js:1:5765)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/store.js:1:2177)
```

The same error happens when trying to test my reducer. It's worth noticing that I'm using react navigation integrated with redux.

Here is the code of my tests for the Login screen:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import Login from "../../src/screens/Login";
import mockStore from "../../__mocks__/redux-mock-store";
import { eventInitialState } from "../../src/redux/reducers";

jest.mock("../../src/navigators/AppNavigator", () => ({
  AppNavigator: {
    router: {
      getStateForAction: jest.fn(),
      getActionForPathAndParams: jest.fn()
    }
  }
}));

describe("Testing login screen", () => {
  it("renders as expected", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login />, {
      context: { store: mockStore(eventInitialState) }
    });
    expect(wrapper.dive()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Here is my login screen (big):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Linking,
  ImageBackground,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  Keyboard,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { login } from "../redux/actions";

import Button from "../components/Button";
import CustomCheckBox from "../components/CustomCheckBox";
import ErrorBox from "../components/ErrorBox";
import { VersaoAmbiente } from "../utils/helpers";

const recuperarSenhaUrl = "my-url";
const backgroundImage = require("../../assets/images/splash.png");
const logoImage = require("../../assets/images/logo-white-v.png");

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...});

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fazerLogin = this.fazerLogin.bind(this);
    this.switch = this.switch.bind(this);
    this.keyboardDidShow = this.keyboardDidShow.bind(this);
    this.keyboardDidHide = this.keyboardDidHide.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      senha: "",
      continuarConectado: true,
      tecladoVisivel: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS !== "ios") {
      this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        "keyboardDidShow",
        this.keyboardDidShow
      );
      this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        "keyboardDidHide",
        this.keyboardDidHide
      );
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS !== "ios") {
      this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
      this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    }
  }

  keyboardDidShow() {
    this.setState({
      tecladoVisivel: true
    });
  }

  keyboardDidHide() {
    this.setState({
      tecladoVisivel: false
    });
  }

  esqueciMinhaSenha = () => {
    Linking.openURL(recuperarSenhaUrl).catch(err => {
      Alert.alert("Ops, um erro ocorreu", err, [{ text: "OK" }], {
        cancelable: false
      });
    });
  };

  fazerLogin() {
    const { email, senha, continuarConectado } = this.state;
    this.props.login(email.trim(), senha.trim(), continuarConectado);
  }

  switch(value) {
    this.setState({ continuarConectado: value });
  }

  mensagemErro() {
    const { erroLogin, erroNegocio } = this.props;
    return erroLogin && erroLogin.response && erroLogin.response.status === 401
      ? "Email ou senha incorretos"
      : erroNegocio && erroNegocio.mensagem
        ? erroNegocio.mensagem
        : "Ops, houve um erro. Tente novamente";
  }

  render() {
    const { erroLogin, logando } = this.props;

    return (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={backgroundImage}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={styles.keyboardViewContainer}
          behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
        >
          <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollView}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentScrollView}
            scrollEnabled={false}
          >
            <Image
              source={logoImage}
              style={{
                marginBottom: 20.7 * 3,
                width: 155,
                height: 125
              }}
            />

            <TextInput
              value={this.state.email}
              placeholder="Usuário"
              style={[styles.input, { marginBottom: 4 * 3 }]}
              placeholderTextColor="#828282"
              maxLength={255}
              autoCorrect={false}
              keyboardType="email-address"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              returnKeyType="done"
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })}
            />

            <TextInput
              value={this.state.senha}
              placeholder="Senha"
              style={styles.input}
              placeholderTextColor="#828282"
              maxLength={255}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              returnKeyType="done"
              secureTextEntry
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ senha: text })}
            />

            <View style={styles.esqueceuView}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.esqueciMinhaSenha}>
                <Text style={styles.esqueceuSenha}>Esqueceu a senha?</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <CustomCheckBox
              style={styles.continuarConectadoView}
              onValueChange={this.switch}
              value={this.state.continuarConectado}
            >
              <Text style={styles.continuarConectadoText}>
                Manter conectado
              </Text>
            </CustomCheckBox>

            <View style={styles.viewButton}>
              <Button
                title="ACESSAR SISTEMA"
                onPress={() => this.fazerLogin()}
                titleStyle={styles.buttonText}
                buttonStyle={styles.button}
                loading={logando}
              />
            </View>
            {erroLogin && (
              <View style={styles.erroBox}>
                <ErrorBox defaultMessage={this.mensagemErro()} />
              </View>
            )}
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        {!this.state.tecladoVisivel && (
          <Text style={styles.versao}>{VersaoAmbiente}</Text>
        )}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    login: (email, senha, continuarConectado) =>
      dispatch(login(email, senha, continuarConectado))
  };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    erroLogin: state.config.erroLogin,
    erroNegocio: state.config.erroNegocio,
    logando: state.config.logando
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);

/* eslint-disable */
Login.propTypes = {
  erroLogin: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.bool]),
  erroNegocio: PropTypes.object,
  logando: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

And, finally, my reducer:

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import AppNavigator from "../navigators/AppNavigator";

const NavigationInitialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction({
  type: NavigationActions.Init
});

const LoggedInInitialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Splash" }),
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Drawer" })
    ]
  }),
  NavigationInitialState
);
const navReducer = (state = NavigationInitialState, action) => {
      let newState;
      let logoutSuccessAction;
      switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_STATE:
          return LoggedInInitialState;
        case LOGIN:
          return LoggedInInitialState;
        case LOGOUT:
          logoutSuccessAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })]
          });
          return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(logoutSuccessAction, state);
        default:
          newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
          break;
      }
      return newState || state;
    };
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: I'm new to jest. I've the same setup and facing exactly the same error, did you find any solution? any help would be appreciated.